# What does this symbol mean ::=?

Tags: sql

I'm reading Joe Celko's book SQL for Smarties, and he uses some notation that's unfamiliar to me. After an internet search, I found some small bits of info about it on Oracle's site.

The symbol he's using that I don't understand is this ::=

My searches turned up very little info, but what I did find was part of a railroad diagram. Here's a link to the one document I found that contains the symbol:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17236_01/epm.1112/esb_tech_ref_1112100/frameset.htm?maxl_bnf_help_symbols.html

Here is one example from the book to describe what I'm talking about:

```
< schema element > ::=
< domain definition > | < table definition > | < view definition > 
| < grant statement > | < assertion definition > | < character set definition >
| < collation definition > | < translation definition >
```

What does the ::= mean?

Comment: wild guess: "the definition (of shema element) is equal to the following"

Comment: I think it's just a slightly modified notation of `=` in [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This symbol is from [*Backus-Naur Form (BNF)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) which is used for syntax description. It is used to separate the name of non-terminal symbol on the left from its definition on the right.

You can read `::=` as "is defined as":

> schema element **is defined as** a domain definition **or** a table definition **or** a view definition **or** ...

Answer (score 0):

Seems to te Back Naur form. It is a notation used to formally describe the use of a grammar. The idea of it is to be independant of the actual language is describing. The :: = represents the assignment.

There is more information for this here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form